# Secure Spring GW route with rewritePath and token relay

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a K8S app with Keycloak, spring GW and backend services as resources services.

Now, it work without authn, but I want to add authn to it using autz code flow.

The question is: this is my `customRouteLocator` in my api gw, how can I modify it so I can add to it the tokenRelay filter?

```java
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("product-service", r -> r.path("/webapi/products/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/webapi/(?<segment>.*)", "/api/v1/${segment}"))
                        .uri("lb://product-service"))
                .route("order-service", r -> r.path("/webapi/orders/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/webapi/(?<segment>.*)", "/api/v1/${segment}"))
                        .uri("lb://order-service"))
                .build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your spring cloud gateway as oauth2 client.

- [Spring security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/index.html)
- [Baeldung Article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-oauth2#1-spring-cloud-gateway-as-an-oauth-20-client)

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Defining the gateway as OAuth2 client in application.yaml:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://[url-to-issuer-in-keycloak]
        registration:
          gateway:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: gateway
            client-secret: <CLIENT SECRET>
            scope: openid
```

Security Chain:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Login(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

After that, you can just apply the token-relay filter to all your routes.
Unfortunately, using the programmatic approach to define routes, you have to apply the token-relay filter to all your routes manually.
The yaml approach offers the possibility to define default filter that are applied to all routes at once:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
      - TokenRelay
```